# Create object array in linq using a dynamic identifier

Tags: c#, linq

I need to obtain a series of objects based on table of the last 30 days. The table has a playing user ,a receiving user and points. The array needs to be based on the highest points given to the receiving user , and then the highest points given to the next receiving user and so on for 30 days.

So **A** gives to **B**, then **B** gives to **C** and **C** gives to **D** etc. until either 30 days is up or a user in the chain did not give anything . Currently i can complete the first 2 gives, but i need to be able to wrap this up somehow in a loop

**Function**

```
public void CalRipple(UserDetail user)
    {
        var filterDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);

        // First User
        var firstUser = context.GamePlay.ToList()
                        .Where(_ => _.PlayingUserId == user.UserDetailId 
                        && _.PlayingDate >= filterDate)
                        .OrderByDescending(_ => _.points)
                        .Select(_ => new GamePlay{
                                     Receiver = _.Receiver,
                                     points = _.points
                               }).FirstOrDefault();

        // Second User
        var secondUser = context.GamePlay
                        .ToList()
                        .Where(_ => _.PlayingUserId == firstUser.Receiver.ReceivingUserId 
                        && _.PlayingDate >= filterDate)
                        .OrderByDescending(_ => _.points)
                        .Select(_ => new GamePlay { 
                                     Receiver = _.Receiver, 
                                     points = _.points
                               }).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

I am not sure how to create a loop so that the item that loops is the user result from the previous query.

Comment: solved .. used a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var finished = false;

        List<GamePlay> res = new List<GamePlay>();
        var currentUser = firstUser;
        while (!finished)
        {
            var nextUser = getBiggestGiveSinceDate(currentUser, res, filterDate);
            if (nextUser == null)
            {
                finished = true;
            }
            else
            {
                res.Add(nextUser);
                currentUser = nextUser;
            }
        }
```